# How to return string representation of self in a class in Python?

Tags: python

Returning self in f1 gives me `<__main__.Test instance at 0x11ae48d40>`.  I would like to be able to return 'apples and cinnamon' but I can't do str(self).  Is there a way for me to do this?

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing
    def f1(self, thing):
        return self + " and " + thing #<<<

a = Test("apples")
a.f1("cinnamon")
```

Comment: Why do you pass "cinnamon" to f1 when you don't actually use it?

Comment: I want to be able to return a string like: Apples and cinnamon by doing return self + " and " + thing, but I can't.

Comment: `apples` is not the string representation of `self`. Did you want to return `self.thing` instead?

Answer (score 5):

To 'pretty print' the object itself, define `__str__` like so:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing

    def __str__(self):
        return self.thing

 >>> a=Test('apple')
 >>> print a
 apple
```

If you want the representation to be custom, add `__repr__`:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.thing 

>>> Test('pear')
pear
```

If you want to create a string as stated in your edit, you can do this:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing

    def andthis(self, other):
        return '{} and {}'.format(self.thing, other)

>>> apple=Test('apple')
>>> apple.andthis('cinnamon')
'apple and cinnamon'
>>> Test('apple').andthis('carrots')
'apple and carrots'
```

Comment: Nope, it will still output <main.Test instance ...> when calling f1(). Try overriding \__repr__

Comment: That would still print `<__main__.Test instance at 0xhexaddress>`; `__str__` is only used when calling `str()` on an object (which is what `print` does).

Answer (score 1):

you should add

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.thing
```

so it looks like this

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing

    def f1(self, thing):
        return str(self) + " and " + thing

    def __str__(self):
        return self.thing

a = Test("apples")
print a
>> "apples"
print a.f1("orange")
>> "apples and orange"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted `f1()` to return a string, then *do so*:

```
def f1(self, otherthing):
    return '{} and {}'.format(self.thing, otherthing)
```

Here we use `str.format()` to put `self.thing` and `otherthing` together into a new string, which is returned. Note that you need to explicitly refer to `self.thing` here.

You could also use string concatenation, like in your own code:

```
def f1(self, otherthing):
    return self.thing + ' and ' + otherthing
```

but again, you need to refer to `self.thing` explicitly.

Demo:

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __init__(self, thing):
...         self.thing = thing
...     def f1(self, otherthing):
...         return '{} and {}'.format(self.thing, otherthing)
... 
>>> a = Test("apples")
>>> a.f1("cinnamon")
'apples and cinnamon'
```